# Handling dynamic text change in span tag

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, ui-automation

After I click the submit button I get one of the two messages below:

1) States information found. Please verify the order PO001007 and then push.

2) Tally push of order no - PO001008 successful

For the success condition I am using this xpath:

```
.//*[@id='wrap']/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/span[text()='Tally push of order no - PO001008 successful']
```

But the text inside is changing every time, so if I use this xpath:

`.//*[@id='wrap']/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/span`

It will make even failed conditions pass. Does anybody know how to handle this dynamic text change inside the span tag?

Below is my html code for both success and failure condition:

```
<div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissable">
<button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
<span>Invalid states information found. Please verify the order PO001007 and then push.</span>
</div>
-----------------------------------------

<div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissable">
<button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
<span>Tally push of order no - PO001008 successful</span>
</div>
```

Comment: what you want to locate Please let me know

Comment: i want to locate <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissable">
<button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
<span>Tally push of order no - PO001008 successful</span>
</div> this element inside span the text will change everytime

Comment: Ok got it,:) dear

Comment: any idea how to handle this

Comment: I posted an xpath try this

Comment: I thinks u got the solution

Comment: hi i said to give id to both success div tag and failure div tag so that i can differenciate both

Comment: hi thank u soo much now it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use this xpath

Try this:

For Unsuccessful Order use this

```
 ///button[@class='close']/following::span[contains(text(),'Invalid')]
```

For successful Order use this

```
//button[@class='close']/following::span[contains(text(),'order no')]
```

Comment: if i get failure message -this div will be replaced with below div  <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissable">
<button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
<span>Invalid states information found. Please verify the order PO001007 and then push.</span>
</div> so this xpath is locating this div too

Comment: so in my success condition it is giving true even for the failure message

Comment: Both the results come on same page

Comment: IT works when span followed by span, if there are multiple spans on same page you have to change it

Comment: i will get any one of the message and the message would be dispalyed in the same position in the same page

Comment: so it give 2 rsults to you?My xpath gives you result or not

Comment: it is giving result for both success and failue..so in my success condition it will return true though i get failure message